# Uninitialized enumerator default values

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Suppose we have followin declaration

```
enum visibility
{
   On  = 0,
   Off = 1,
   maxVisibility
};
```

Is the guaranteed value of `maxVisibility` enumerator `2` in C++11/C++0x standard ?

Comment: I would also suggest you to use strongly-typed enumerations: `enum class visibility { ... }`, since you can use c++11 features.

Comment: By the way, *C++0x* isn't a standard, it was an unofficial name for *C++11* before it became a standard. But I'm just nit-picking.

Comment: @ChristianRau C++11 is an equally unofficial name... it is just somewhat easier to type and remember than ISO/IEC 14882:2011.

Comment: @Lundin Well, true indeed. I should really stop nit-picking if I cannot live up to the responsibility for perfect exactness that comes with it. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed.

§ 7.2.2

> If the first enumerator has no initializer,the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition without an initializer **gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous enumerator by one**.

Comment: So you can even drop the explicit `0` and `1`.